# Getting and displaying data from database with xforms on submission

Tags: xslt, xforms, orbeon

I have a database with an xml document in it, and I want to display a transformed xml on my xforms page, when the submission is sent (I'm using orbeon forms).

My solution is, that on the submission my servlet gets the xml from the database, writes it into a file, xslt transforms the xml tree (when and how should I do the transformation?), but I don't know, how to display this file on the xforms page. Maybe the replace="instance" attribute in  can help, but i don't know how.

Thanks!

Now, after Alessandro's advice, Im trying to use this xpl thing, but it doesn't work.
In the model:

```
<xforms:insert nodeset="instance('inst2')"
origin="xxforms:call-xpl('oxf:/resources/pipeline.xpl', 'data', 
instance('inst1'), 'data')"/>
```

in pipeline.xpl:

```
<p:config xmlns:p="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/pipeline"
      xmlns:oxf="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/processors">

<p:param type="input" name="data"/>
<p:param type="output" name="data"/>

<p:processor name="oxf:xslt">
    <p:input name="data" href="#data"/>
    <p:input name="config" href="transform.xsl"/>
    <p:output name="data" ref="data"/>
</p:processor>
```

My instance, that I want to transform is "complaint-instance", the transformed instance called "trf-instance", the pipeline.xpl file is in the same directory with my xforms page. My styesheet called customerToOperator.xsl. What's wrong in my code?

I just noticed, the note: "If you are using separate deployment, the service and XSLT transformation must be present in the Orbeon WAR file, instead of within your application."
Ehm... Where should I put these files?

my app in details:

a) an xforms page, with 2 instances:

```
<instance id='inst1'>
<name>
   <lastname/>
   <firstname/>
</name>  
</instance>

<instance id='inst2'>
<fname>
   <fullname/>
</fname>
</instance>
```

I got 2 input fields, referenced on name/lastname and name/firstname.
I have an xforms:insert node, described above, and an xforms:submission node:

```
<xforms:submission 
id="save-submission" 
ref="instance('inst2')"
action="/my-servlet"
method="post"
replace="none">
```

I added 2 files to orbeon/WEB-INF/resources, the pipeline.xpl, (described above) and transform.xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
          <fname>
              <fullname>
                 <xsl:value-of select="name/firstname"/>
                 <xsl:value-of select="name/lastname"/>
              </fullname>
          </fname>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And I have a servlet, which writes the posted instance on the console (now it writes inst2 on the console, but without the user input data, only the nodes...)

A really need to fix this...

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the XML from a database (relational or not) and apply a transformation, instead of writing my own servlet, I would use an [XPL pipeline](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xml-pipeline-language-xpl), and map this pipeline to a URL through the page flow. Now you have a service that answers to an HTTP request and returns XML. To call the service from XForms, you use an `<xforms:submission replace="instance">`. You end up with the XML in an instance, and you can display it with something like: `<xforms:output value="saxon:serialize(instance(), 'xml')"/>`.

In all cases (including separate deployment), the pipeline and XSLT file must be in the "resources". Usually, this means the `WEB-INF/resources` of the Orbeon's web app. But you can also do more fancy things by setting up the Orbeon [resource manager](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/resource-managers) to also use other directories on disk.

Comment: Everything in your code looks right to me. I added some more details on where the pipeline and XSLT should go. If you can put them in the Orbeon's web app `WEB-INF/resources`, then you should be all good.

Comment: it doesn't work: /
I described my app in details in the question...
I'm sure, i'm missing something

Comment: @Anvar, it might just be a path issue: when you use the `oxf:/` scheme, Orbeon Forms looks for files in what's called the "resources". Resources can be stored in a number of places, including `WEB-INF/resources`. So if you have a file `WEB-INF/resources/pipeline.xpl`, you want to references it as `oxf:/pipeline.xpl` (not `oxf:/resources/pipeline.xpl`). Also, when something doesn't quite work the way you want, have a look at the `orbeon.log`. In lots of cases, you'll find the reason why things don't work there. I hope this helps!

Comment: @avernet Okay, now i'm logging everything. How is it possible, that if I search the log for `pipeline.xpl` or `inst2`, it founds nothing? It should, isn't it? And even if I put syntax errors in pipeline.xpl, it doesn't logs a word.... I changed the url to `oxf:/pipeline.xpl`...

Comment: @Anvar, when you say it "doesn't work", do you have an error in the web browser? If not, do you have an exception in the orbeon.log? At the beginning of the exception, does it say something that helps you solve the problem? If not, I will need to reproduce this here to be able to help further, and for this, I'll need a package with the simplest reproducible test case you can come up with.

Comment: @avernet I'm not sure, you could read my last comment (because I get your comment only after 19 hours... :S)
There isn't any error neither in the browser, nor in the orbeon log. (orbeon.log doesn't even mention the pipeline.xpl or the inst2 word, i searched for it...) It looks like orbeon just ignores my <insert> tag...

Comment: @Anvar, I could read your last comment, but it isn't surprising that `pipeline.xpl` doesn't show in the log. The log is incredibly verbose when it comes to XForms, telling you every little thing it does, but doesn't log much when it comes to pipeline execution, except when there are errors. But your comment about the `<xforms:insert>` maybe not running is intriguing. Could you try replacing the `<xforms:insert>` by `<xforms:message>Been here!</xforms:message>` and see if you get an alert for that message? If not, this is an issue with the XForms code, which just doesn't run that action.

Comment: Yeah, finally, it works. It was totally my bad (of course), I didn't write the `<xforms:insert>` inside an `<xforms:action>` element, so it was never called... replacing with <xforms:message> helped me to figure this out. 
Thanks (&virtual beer) Alessandro!